# Running 32bit program using python 64bit

Tags: python, 64-bit, 32-bit, os.system

I want to run a program through python using os.system or subprocess.call or whatever, but this program is a 32bit program and my python is 64bit and cannot find this program in order to run it. What is the easiest way for running the program through python?

Some more details:
I'm using ubuntu, running python 2.7, installed ia32-libs (the program runs perfectly from the command line), running python using idle.

Thanks!

=============(Later that day)=============

OK, got it. The problem is when working with IDLE only (dono why). Using other guis (iron python, eclipse) does not return an error.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

```
subprocess.call("command param1 param2", shell=True)
```

works for me. Are you sure it's a 32/64 bit problem?

Comment: I'm sure. Your suggestion is not working and returns error code 127 (as if the file is not existing) and believe me I checked the path...

Comment: As Arne also can't reproduce you problem, maybe you're really facing a PATH-issue? Have you tried using an absolute path? It would have surprised me if it didn't work, as `subprocess.call` opens a completely new shell, which runs in a separate process, and thus is not linked to your 64bit Python in any way. In this shell, the 32bit program is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

I have to concur with Thorsten: this should work fine. I tested it using 64bit python2.6 on Debian stable and using xsnow 32bit:

```
$ file $(which python2.6)
/usr/bin/python2.6: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped

$ file ~/bin/xsnow 
/home/myuser/bin/xsnow: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, stripped
aschmitz@dpcl001:~

$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 26 2010, 22:31:48) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call( "~/bin/xsnow", shell=True )
Xsnow-1.42, December 14th 2001 by Rick Jansen (rja@euronet.nl)
WWW: http://www.euronet.nl/~rja/Xsnow/
```

Can you provide an example code that fails?